# PySpark df.write is loading different number of records into different tables

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've a dataframe called `df_result` that has 36 records. I need to load this dataframe into a two different tables in SQL Server. I'm trying to use two different modes: `append` and `overwrite` in pyspark to load these tables. But the result I see doesn't make sense.

I have two target tables:

`TableA (empty)`

`TableB (contains data)`

I need to load `df_result` into these two tables but with different `modes`.

My code is as follows:

*For TableA (which is empty):*

`df_result.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='abc.TableA', mode = 'append')`

Loads all 36 records from `df_result` as expected.

*For TableB (which has data):*

`df_result.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table='abc.TableB', mode = 'overwrite')`

Loads only 18 records from `df_result` which is strange.

Schema of the dataframe and DDLs of both tables are as follows:

```
df_result

root
 |-- SID: decimal(19,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LocName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cnumber: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- StartDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- EndDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- CurrentIND: string (nullable = true)



TableA:

CREATE TABLE [abc].[TableA]
(
    [SID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [LocName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Cnumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentIND] [char](1) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
);


TableB:

CREATE TABLE [abc].[TableB]
(
    [SID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [LocName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Cnumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentIND] [char](1) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
);
```

I expect both `TableA` and `TableB` to have the same data, at least the first time I run it because `TableA` is empty although in `append` mode. But it is not the case as both lines load different number of records.

This is very strange as both the lines are supposed to do the same thing. I'm unable to understand what is going wrong here.  Can someone please shed some light on what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the schema of `df_result` and DDL for both tables?

Comment: @mazaneicha added the DDLs  in the question just now.

Comment: Hmmm... So defs for TableA and TableB are basically identical. Maybe there are some constraints defined on TableB that would cause records to be dropped?

Comment: Just checked in SSMS.. No constraints on either of these tables.. The constraints folder is totally empty.